# Add Build Settings for xcodeuild in Ant Script

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ant

I want to run this working line of code in ant-script:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild ARCHS="armv7 armv7s" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -workspace \APPNAME.xcworkspace -scheme APPNAMETarget build
```

So far I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <project name="APPNAME" default="debugbuild" basedir=".">
        <target name="debugbuild">
            <echo message="Building debug build of APPNAME" />
            <exec executable="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild" os="Mac OS X">
                <arg value="-workspace"/>
                <arg value="APPNAME.xcworkspace"/>
                <arg value="-scheme"/>
                <arg value="APPNAMETarget"/>
                <arg value="build"/>
            </exec>
        </target>
    </project>
```

But I also need to add Build Settings (ARCHS="armv7 armv7s" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO) but don't know how to add them in the script. I tried

```
<env key="ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH" value="NO"/>
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried passing them as args, in the same positions as in your working line of code?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I already found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I just had to add them as arguments like the other but I had to get rid of the parenthesis which were fine in the command line. I hope it is helpful for other because I spend some time on this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project name="APPNAME" default="debugbuild" basedir=".">
    <target name="debugbuild">
        <echo message="Building debug build of APPNAME" />
        <exec executable="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild" os="Mac OS X">
            <arg value="-workspace"/>
            <arg value="APPNAME.xcworkspace"/>
            <arg value="-scheme"/>
            <arg value="APPNAMETarget"/>
            <arg value="build"/>
            <arg value="ARCHS=armv7 armv7s"/>
            <arg value="ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: It is helpful for me!.

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I specify signing identity and provisioning profile from ANT script.

Comment: The mashine that rans the ant-script must have the provisioning profile and the signing identity installed. You can specify the arguments just like I did in my post. The arguments are "exportSigningIdentity" and "exportInstallerIdentity" i guess. But I never tried it. Just look at the [xcodebuild command list](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html). There is an example on the bottom of the page how to use it.